# How do I display different alert view functionality when doing error handling with Enum + Switch?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have a ViewController class that has couple textfields that get passed as parameters in the Authenticator class. What I want to know is how can I have different alertView error codes using the enums. I cannot access the enum from the ViewController class.

```
class ViewController {
    var full_name : String?
    var age : Int?
    private var auth: Authenticator()

    auth_user (full_name: String?, age: Int?) {
          .....
         try auth.verify_name(full_name: String?) 
         try auth.verify_age(age: Int?)

    }

}

class Auth {
   ....
   enum AuthError: Error {
       case ageIsBelow13
       case invalidAge
       case invalidName

   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `enum AuthError` outside the `class Auth` then you can access it anywhere in your code